# Clarification on mod_rewrite issue needed

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, short

I have a URL that is being generated using GET variables from a form in PHP.  The issue that I have is that there are two variables being passed.  Here is an example URL to clarify:

```
http://www.examplesite.com/example.php?first=one&second=two
```

I would like to use a mod_rewrite in my .htaccess to make this a smaller URL.  Ideally I would like the URL...

```
http://www.examplesite.com/one
```

to be able to redirect to the full URL...

```
http://www.examplesite.com/example.php?first=one&second=two
```

but as you can see there are two variables.  Is this possible?  If not, what is the shortest that I can get the URL using both variables?

Here is my current attempt to solve this with a mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on  

# don't rewrite if the file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# don't rewrite if the directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.php?first=$1&second=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on  

# don't rewrite if the file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# don't rewrite if the directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# http://www.examplesite.com/one/two
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /example.php?first=$1&second=$2 [L]
```